# Why isn't my array storing floating point values?

Tags: arrays, c, input, scanf

i want to take input for array element, input can be anything other than char,(can be float,negative), but my code is storing  0.000000 as input.

```
int n; 
scanf("%d", &n);

if (n > 0)
{
    float arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the element %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &arr[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: How do you know what is stored? Also why don't you check the success of `scanf()` callls?

Comment: Modern compilers typically give warning if you use wrong conversion specifier. If you didn't get a warning, check your compiler settings that such warnings are enabled.

Answer (score 3):

The `%lf` specifier for `scanf` is for "long" floating point values, or `double`.

For `float` values you should use only `%f`.

Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.